# Free Pascal IDE crashed when opening or saving to

Tags: ide, runtime-error, freepascal

I'm having problems running the FreePascal IDE (for Win32 for i386) Version 1.0.12 2011/04/23 Compiler Version 2.4.4. It crashes when I want to "Open" and "Save as"

When I select one of those options in the Menu the IDE returns: "Program generated a RTE 215 at address $00696A49" which prompts me to close the IDE, and then shows three addresses in a separate window: $00696A49 and 2 others (random).

If you need to know, I have been loading .pas files from directories other than FP's own, and the IDE used to show "couldn't load file from current directory"-like messages.

I want to know what's generating this problem and if I have to update it.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Free Pascal Error Images - Stack Overflow]

[image: Free Pascal Error Images - Stack Overflow]

[image: Free Pascal Error Images - Stack Overflow]

Comment: RTE 215 is an integer overflow (EIntOverflow, if exceptions were being used). This sounds like a bug in the IDE itself. Can you create new files and save them normally, instead of opening existing files?

Comment: I can't save them inside the IDE, but I can create the .pas files with Notepad, then opening them with FP using "Open as..." with the right-click, but can't save them again if I make changes (I'd have to quit the IDE and make changes with Notepad.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite 2.4.4 being an older release, it shouldn't happen with a win32 release in normal situations (like on harddisk, not network drive, no special permissions in sight).

You could try using a different system and see if it fails there too, or try a newer version.

Comment: Tested in Vista and it didn't get any error, so I'll uninstall fp here and install 2.6.4